# PHP foreach loop syntax escape '

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop in php that works fine when I hardcode a value like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['icons'] as $icon) {

    $sql .= "('756','$icon'),";
}
```

My issue is that I have to insert a session variable instead:

$row_gbl_ltg['EmpNo']

But when I insert this I get a 500 internal server error I am assuming because of the use of ' like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['icons'] as $icon) {

    $sql .= "('$row_gbl_ltg['EmpNo']','$icon'),";
}
```

I've tried to escape the ' with a \' but it does not work...how do I escape this properly and still insert my value?

Comment: `"('{$row_gbl_ltg['EmpNo']}','$icon'),";` Note the curly braces around the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually  do it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['icons'] as $icon) {

    $sql .= '("' . $row_gbl_ltg['EmpNo'] . '", "' . $icon . '"),';
}
```

Remember to remove the last comma before you actually execute your query.

Comment: instead of checking the boring last coma, you should store each part of SQL in an array (`$sql` should be an array). And at the end of your `foreach`, you just have to `implode` the array with ',' to retrieve your entiere SQL well formatted :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$sql .= "('" . $row_gbl_ltg['EmpNo'] . "','$icon'),";
```

You can play with ' and " but there is some limitations when accessing associated array.

And as @Captain Payalytic said, you can also play with `{ }` aroud your var as 2nd solution.
`{ }` explain better to PHP where begin and end a var that we want to be used/interpreted.

Comment: Just make sure you properly sanitise those variables to prevent SQL injection!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the other answer:

```
 $sql .= "('{$row_gbl_ltg['EmpNo']}','$icon'),";
```